# To get data only when all rows are of same value

Tags: oracle

I have following data-

**Status_table table**

[image]

I want to filter this data as follows-

**OK** - This should return num(11) if any of the row has value 'OK'.

```
Select distinct Num from Status_table where status = 'ok') -- Working fine
```

**No** - This should return num(11) if any of the row has value 'NO'.

```
Select distinct Num from Status_table where status = 'No') -- Working fine
```

**Yes**- This should return '11' only when all the values are 'Yes'
I write following query

```
Select distinct Num from Status_table where status = 'yes')
```

This is not working as it will list '11' but I want to list it only when all status are 'Yes'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current queries are potentially inefficient for large data sets, and wouldn't scale well.

It might be better to:

```
Select Num
from   Status_table
where  status = 'ok' and
       rownum = 1;

Select Num
from   Status_table
where  status = 'No' and
       rownum = 1;
```

These would stop scanning the table when the required value was found.

For the 'Yes' query:

```
Select Num
from   Status_table
where  status = 'Yes' and
       rownum = 1     and 
       not exists (
         select null
         from   Status_table
         where  status != 'Yes')
```

This would scan the table until one row with 'Yes' is found, and if it is then it would check for the non-existence of any other value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on `(Num, Status)`, this will be quite efficient:

```
SELECT Num 
FROM Status_table 
GROUP BY Num
HAVING MIN(status) = 'yes'
   AND MAX(status) = 'yes' ;
```

No subqueries and no counting. Only an index scan will be needed.

Comment: This can be a good solution if column has index on them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t(id, num, status) AS
     ( SELECT 1, 11, 'yes' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 2, 11, 'yes' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 3, 11, 'yes' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 4, 11, 'yes' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 5, 11, 'yes' FROM dual
     )
SELECT DISTINCT num
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     (SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM t GROUP BY status HAVING status <> 'yes'
     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query should return the value in the num if the status are all Yes then give this a try

```
select distinct Num from status_table
where 
upper(status)=upper(decode((select count(*) "Count" from status_table where upper(status)!=upper('yes')),0,'Yes',NULL))
```